# Determining successful login to HTTPS

Tags: android, http, https

I have an app that must connect to a server using HTTPS. I can login just fine, but the way I determine if that login is successful is ugly and kind of a hack; instead of relying on HTTP status lines and codes, I instead search the HttpResponse entity for a specific string that I know is there when I successfully login. Like I said, ugly and kind of a hack. I was researching ways to optimize this process, and I came upon using HTTP status codes and status lines. Great, I thought. The "200" code should be returned when I successfuly login. The problem is, that "200" code is just returned when the server successfully gets the response; I can put in bad login information or good information and still get a 200 code. My very broad and open-ended question: is there a way to determine successful login that's prettier than my current method? I can provide more of my code if needed.

Comment: Do you control the server, or is the login handled by a third party?

Comment: The server is my school's, so it's not handled at all by me in the slightest. To further complicate things, the IT department has been understandably unresponsive in my asking how the server handles these request.